# Не отправляется файл

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="upload_form" role="form" action="javascript:void(0);" onsubmit="upload_file()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
         <input type="file" name="filename" class="form-control" placeholder="Название файла">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></span> Загрузить
    </button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function upload_file() {
    var msg = $("#upload_form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "function/upload_file.php",
        data: msg,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#result").html(data);
        },
        error:  function(xhr, str){
            alert("Возникла ошибка!");
        }
    });
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($filename)) upload('filename');
function upload($filename) {
    $connect = ftp_connect('*****');
    $connect_login = ftp_login($connect, '*******', '******');
    ftp_chdir($connect, 'my/');
    $tmp    = $_FILES[$filename]['tmp_name'];
    $aname  = $_FILES[$filename]['name'];
    if (ftp_put($connect, $aname, $tmp, FTP_BINARY)) {
        echo "Успех";
    }
    else {
        echo "Неудача";
    }
    ftp_close($connect);
    unlink($tmp);
    };
?>
```

Comment: Через $.ajax() файлы так просто не передаются. Тут надо или [File API][1], или [FormData][2].

P.S. Вот, кстати, уже [коллега уже описывал тут][3], как это делать.

   [1]:http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/
   [2]:http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-XMLHttpRequest2-20100907/#the-formdata-interface
   [3]:http://hashcode.ru/questions/222137/php-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-ajax

Answer (score 1):

воспользуйтесь вот этим плагином: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/